# What is the order of destruction for variables initialized through constructor initialization set?

Tags: c++

suppose I have class A,B and C

if I then have container as follows

```
Container::Container()
:A(10),B(20),C(30)
{
   //Do something specific
}
```

Now if I call the destructor of Container, i.e ~Container()
I notice that destructors are getting called in the reverse order
i.e ~C(), ~B() and then ~A()

Is this something always fixed order? 
Can anyone throw some more light on the order of destructors for construction initialization set ?

Answer (score 7):

The order is fixed, but not by the initialization list.

It's the reverse order in which the members are declared in the class.

```
class Container
{
   A a;
   B b;
   C c;
};
```

When a `Container` object is destroyed, the order in which the members are destroyed is `c`, `b` and `a`.

Some compilers will warn you if you initialize members in a different order than they were declared, and it's good to keep consistency.

Comment: Yes, i get it now. So if i jumble up the order of declaration/or initialization order, the order of destruction may get messed up. Makes sense to keep consistency between declaration and initialization. I knew about this rule, but did not know it applied to construction initialization set as well.

Comment: @rajshenoy well, the order of destruction will change, but it's not messed up. It will still be well-defined. :)

Comment: @rajshenoy but yes, if you exchange b and c in my example, then b will get destroyed first.

Answer (score 6):

They are always destroyed in reverse order of construction. The order of construction is always the order of declaration, regardless of the order in the initializer list.

Answer (score 3):

Members (and non-virtual subobjects) are constructed in the order in which they are declared, and destroyed in reverse order. The order of initializers in the initializer list is unrelated, but is strongly recommended to be the same, just to keep yourself and everyone around you sane.

Imagine you had this:  `Foo(int n) : a(n), b(a) { }`. This looks good, but if `Foo::b` was actually declared before `Foo::a`, this might be undefined behaviour (if `b`'s constructor requires a complete type). To guard against this, you should always enable and respect the relevant compiler warnings.

Comment: Whether this is UB depends on the ctors of `b`. If `B::B` just takes and stores an `A&`, it's well-defined. A similar case is passing `*this` to a member object so it knows its parent. That too "mentions" an object before it's constructed.